# Cookie Session not works on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, session-cookies

I'm developing an ASP.net application that shows a message that can be minimized, maximized or close. These functionality must be maintain while browser is open. When user open a new browser the message will be shown as it's inital state.

Cookies are chosen to store the user election: minimized, maximized or closed. I used jQuery and jQuery.Cookie to manage this, but I can't create session cookies that only stores while browser is open. All cookies I create are persistent. How can do that using this plugin of jQuery?

This line of code is an example of how I set the cookie:

```
$.cookie(cookieName, 'Minimized', { path: '/' });
```

As you can show on the title of the question, I need that this work on IE8 (other browsers are not supported).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested on Firefox and Chrome and works fine. It seems that has to be something related with the user I'm using to test it. I think IE8 that understand in a good way Administrator privileges.